# MongoDB more optimized approach than multiple distinct("key1.key2") or aggregate $group + $addToSet

Tags: mongodb

I have follow collection:

```
User{
  _id:
  data: {
    languages: ["English", "Chinese", "Spanish"..],
    books: ["foo", "bar"..],
    courses_taken: ["Physics", "Math"..],
    ..
  }
  ..
}
User{
  _id:
  data: {
    languages: ["Russian", "Arabic"..],
    books: ["xyz"],
    ..
  }
  ..
}
```

We have APIs that expose all the distinct values of each above fields and generate such as the response.

```
{
  lanuages: ["English", "Chinese", "Spanish", "Russian", "Arabic"..],
  books: ["foo", "bar", "xyz"]
   ..
}
```

I looked through the source code and found out above is accomplished using a single aggregate command as follows:

```
db.getCollection("user").aggregate([
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": null,
          "languages": {
            "$addToSet": "$data.languages"
          }
          "books": {
            "$addToSet": "$data.books"
          }
          ...
        }
      }
])
```

Above do give expected result but we keep on getting alerts from MongoDB Altas warning about full document scan - `COLLSCAN`. I am facing a problem where `$group` doesn't perform on index data and doing `distinct()` would require firing such query n times, plus our n is quite large (50+). Is there any way to combine the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one Group stage. That's the reason.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes)

> The $group stage can sometimes use an index to find the first
> document in each group if all of the following criteria are met:
>
> The $group stage is preceded by a $sort stage that sorts the field to
> group by,
>
> There is an index on the grouped field which matches the
> sort order and
>
> The only accumulator used in the $group stage is
> $first.

1. You don't have sort stage
2. Group field is null for your use case
3. You need $addToSet

Unfortunately, your only option is to add a `Sort` stage as your first stage with indexed field. Then it would use index than COLLSCAN.